# How do you get or display the path of an absolute link using PHP?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I know that this is a simple question but I am trying to link to a php page from within a php template. My template is located at: 
wp-content/themes/maton-theme/main.php

And the file that I am linking to is in the same directory I tried a few things but my code is wrong.

```
<a href="<?php $url = includes_url('post-2.php'); ?>">Link</a>
```

I also tried linking by using a simple:

```
<a href="post-2.php">Link</a>
```

But it didn't work since I am using a theme, the link goes to `http://local.test.com/main/post-2.php` and I get a Page not found error.

How can I link to another php file within the same directory? Also, Is there a way to show the whole URL path?

Comment: where did you put post-2.php file ?

Comment: @Ryan AW in the same directory as main.php

Comment: make a directory called main in your root, and put the post-2.php file in it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing what you are doing. It would be better to just create a post in WordPress with a custom template and link to that. However I could missing the reason why you would need to do this. So what you need to do is get the template directory URL using `get_template_directory_uri()`.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/post-2.php">Link</a>
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/